# Avalonia UI UserControl Background depending on Theme

Tags: .net, xaml, avaloniaui

I'd like to use light-colored image as a UserControl Background if application works with Light theme, and a dark-colored image if theme is Dark.

So, something like [this](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/guides/styles-and-resources/how-to-use-theme-variants), but I failed to put ImageBrush element in ResourcesDictionary - IDE returns  an error that it can't find an ImageBrush definition in ResourcesDictionary.

I've prepared a dark image and a light one. How can I define background path depending on Theme variant?